# Is it possible to include module per object in ruby?

Tags: ruby, mixins

Is it possible to include module per instance in ruby?

i.e. in Scala, you can do the following.

```
val obj = new MyClass with MyTrait
```

can you do something similar in ruby, maybe something similar to following?

```
obj = Object.new include MyModule
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
obj = Object.new
obj.extend MyModule
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, see [Object#extend](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Object.html#method-i-extend). All objects have the `extend` method, which takes a list of modules as its arguments. Extending an object with a module will add all instance methods from the module as instance methods on the extended object.

```
module Noise
  def cluck
    p "Cluck cluck!"
  end
end

class Cucco
end

anju = Cucco.new
anju.extend Noise
anju.cluck

==> "Cluck cluck!"
```